# No funciona método onblur

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema al validar un formulario con JavaScript. Resulta que quiero que cuando el usuario seleccione un fecha y sea mayor a la actual me lance una alerta diciendo que la fecha no debe ser mayor a la del presente día. Esto funciona siempre y cuando seleccione mas de una vez el input y este pierda el foco, por que a la primera no sucede nada, hay que tener en cuenta que utilizo la clase tcal para mostrar un calendario. pdt: no puedo hacerlo con el onclick sobre el submit.

**SCRIPT**

```
function validarFecha(){  

    var hoy = new Date();
    var dd = hoy.getDate();
    var mm = hoy.getMonth()+1; //hoy es 0!
    var yyyy = hoy.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

    hoy = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

    var fechatanqueo = document.getElementById('FECHA_TANQUEO').value;

    if(hoy < fechatanqueo){
      alert("La fecha de tanqueo no puede ser mayor a la fecha actual");
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<td><input type="text" name="FECHA_TANQUEO" id="FECHA_TANQUEO" class="tcal" onblur="validarFecha('hoy', 'fechatanqueo')"/></td>
```

Comment: A mi me salta el alert al perder el foco despues de escribir por primera vez.

Comment: el punto es que tengo la clase `tcal`que hace que al presionar el input se me despliegue un calendario.

Comment: Desconozco el plugin que da esa clase, y no se como tratas el código, pero en vez del método onblur ¿has probado el método onchange? si haces un evento onchange al input y ejecutas una función, se ejecutará cuando haya cambios en el input

Answer (score 1):

En vez de usar el evento blur podrías usar keyPress

```
//HTML
<input id="myinput" onKeyPress="checkDate(event)"/>

// JS
function checkDate(ev) {
  var date = ev.currentTarget.value + String.fromCharCode(ev.charCode);
  if(date.match(/\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d/)) {
    validarFecha(date);
  }
}

function validarFecha(date){
    var hoy = new Date();
    var userDateSplited = date.split('-');
    var userDate = new Date(userDateSplited[2],userDateSplited[1], userDateSplited[0]);

    if(hoy.getTime() < userDate.getTime()){
      alert("La fecha de tanqueo no puede ser mayor a la fecha actual");
    }

}
```

Comment: Se supone que este evento se activa cuando se presiona una tecla, el punto que es que tengo la clase `tcal` que hace que al presionar sobre el input se despliegue un calendario. aparte probé el código y no funciona.

Comment: Me imagino que estas usando algún plugin, quizás ese plugin maneje algún callback para cuando se ha seleccionado una fecha.